# How to extend WP_Widget_Media

Tags: widgets, media

I am new to WordPress theme development. I'd like to create a new widget based on the built-in Image widget, with additional fields such as 'description' & 'speaker'... etc. The widget is called 'My Poster'. I added the file poster.php and it is like:

```
class WP_Widget_Media_Poster extends WP_Widget_Media
{
    parent::__construct(
        'media_poster', __('My Poster'),
        array(
            'description' => __('Displays a Poster.'),
            'mime_type'   => 'image',
        )
    );
    :
    :
```

I already added the required code to function.php as follow:

- require_once get_template_directory() . '/widgets/poster.php';
- register_widget('WP_Widget_Media_Poster');

I can see the new widget in the "Available Widgets" page, and I am able to add it to my sidebar. However, the original field "Title" and the "Add Image" button do not show up. Only the 'Delete' and 'Done' links appear at the bottom.

[image]

Two questions:

1. is this the right approach to create this new widget by extending the built-in WP_Widget_Media class? if so,
2. how to properly do it?

Thank you.

brian

Comment: Is that your exact code? Where is the class constructor? It looks like you've placed a function call inside a class but not in a function, I would expect this to generate a PHP fatal error, and there are random colons `:`

Comment: this is a clone of the original built-in WP_Widget_Media class

Comment: Do you mean you copy pasted the `WP_Widget_Media` class, renamed it, and added `extends WP_Widget_Media`? I'm confused by what you mean, edit your question to remove the code block and add a new code block that accurately reflects what you did, your current code could not have produced the results in your screenshot, it should be generating PHP syntax errors, it's extremely confusing